# SendMessage WM_SETTEXT does not work on another application from MFC application

Tags: c++, winforms, winapi, mfc

I am trying to set the text in an Edit control of another application from a C++ MFC application.

My code works fine if the other application is Notepad but it doesn't work on the application that I need it to work on. When I couldn't get WM_SETTEXT to work I thought maybe the application is filtering the messages to the control and since keyboard input works I tried sending keyboard messages. That also did not work. I verified that the window does receive keyboard input by logging messages in Spy++. What am I doing wrong or missing?

```
if (g_IPAdressHwnd != 0) // g_IPAdressHwnd is the handle to the Edit control
{
    CWnd *wnd = CWnd::FromHandle(g_IPAdressHwnd);
    wchar_t buff[256];
    wchar_t windowText[256];
    wchar_t className[256];

    BOOL b = IsWindowUnicode(wnd->GetSafeHwnd()); // returns true

    GetClassName(wnd->GetSafeHwnd(), className, 200); // returns "WindowsForms10.EDIT.app.0.378734a"

    wnd->GetWindowText(windowText, 256);    // does not work
    wnd->SendMessage(WM_GETTEXT, 256, (LPARAM)buff); // this works

    wcscpy_s(buff, L"Foo!");
    wnd->SendMessage(WM_SETTEXT, 256, (LPARAM)buff);    // does not work

    wnd->SendMessage(WM_CHAR, L'A', 0);  // does not work
}
```

Comment: Check the return value from [`SendMessage`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendmessage).  If it indicates an error, call `GetLastError` to find out why it failed.

Comment: What makes you think that the window class, `WindowsForms10.EDIT.app.0.378734a`, recognizes a WM_SETTEXT message?

Comment: The return value from SendMessage is 0. I assume that means there was not an error.

Comment: It is the same window class as other applications I tested with that did recognize WM_TEXT. So yes it was kind of an assumption but I also have the same issue with WM_CHAR. When I log messages in Spy++ I verify that keyboard input sends WM_CHAR and inputs text. When I try that with SendMessage it does not work

Comment: Does the control only accept IP address format? If yes, why do you try to send letters?

Comment: No, that was just some random text I put in the Edit control so I could search for it using WM_GETTEXT.

Comment: `WM_SETTEXT` returns 0 on failure, it's in the docs.

Answer (score 3):

I called GetLastError() after SendMessage() even though SendMessage() returned 0. The last error was 5 which is access denied. Caused by UIPI.

My application needs to run at a higher integrity level.

Turns out I simply needed to run Visual Studio as administrator which in turn runs my application in debug mode as administrator. This also means the final application will always need to be run in administrator mode to work but that will be fine.